# latex todonotes-package throws error in combination with ieeeojies.cls document class

Tags: latex

When I am trying to use the todonotes-package within the IEEE OJIES template, by just adding `\usepackage{todonotes}`,  latex throws a *“Missing number, treated as zero.”* error.
It seems to me that something is in conflict with things in the *ieeeojies.cls* class-file. If I use the *IEEEtran.cls* as a document class, no error is thrown.

Here is the link to the template in overleaf:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-open-journal-of-the-industrial-electronics-society-template/nhkhktxkdsgf

I am used to work with the todonotes-package, so can please somebody with more latex experience help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the naughty redefinition of `\year` in the class.

You can avoid the error by loading `pgf` before the class so it still gets to see the correct definition of year instead of the strange things the class does to it

```
\RequirePackage{pgf}
\documentclass{ieeeojies}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\EOD

\end{document}
```